# Using geoprocessing tool clip in arcpy

Tags: python, clip, arcpy

i'm trying to use geoprocessing tools in arcpy (specifically buffer & clip) but keep getting this error message

Update: Thanks for answering my question, I think I corrected it though and I still get the same error

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features=(r"C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\LabData\NA_Big_Lakes.shp"), out_feature_class="C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/Buffered_Lakes6.shp", buffer_distance_or_field="50000 Meters", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="ROUND", dissolve_option="ALL", dissolve_field="", method="PLANAR")

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(folderpath + "\NA_Big_Lakes.shp", folderpath +\
                  "\Buffered_Lakes6", "50000 meters")

arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features=(r"C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\LabData\NA_Cities.shp"), clip_features="C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/LabData/Buffered_Lake5.shp", out_feature_class="C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/LabData/Clipped_Cities2", cluster_tolerance="")

arcpy.Clip_analysis(folderpath + "\NA_Cities.shp", folderpath + \
                "\Buffered_Lakes5.shp", folderpath + "\Clipped_Cities2")
```

When I run it I get the same error as before but with the path instead of just the file.

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset NA_Cities.shp does not exist or is not supported
ERROR 000732: Clip Features: Dataset Buffered_Lake5.shp does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Clip).
```

Here is my code I'm new to programming so not easy to spot what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!!

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

print 'Identifying the cities now...'


arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features=(r"C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\LabData\NA_Big_Lakes.shp"), out_feature_class="C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/Buffered_Lakes6.shp", buffer_distance_or_field="50000 Meters", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="ROUND", dissolve_option="ALL", dissolve_field="", method="PLANAR")

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(folderpath + "\NA_Big_Lakes.shp", folderpath +\
                  "\Buffered_Lakes6", "50000 meters")

arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features="NA_Cities.shp", clip_features="Buffered_Lake5.shp", out_feature_class="C:\Users\Michaelf\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Clipped_Cities2", cluster_tolerance="")

arcpy.Clip_analysis(folderpath + "\NA_Cities.shp", folderpath + \
                "\Buffered_Lakes5.shp", folderpath + "\Clipped_Cities2")
```

Comment: You need to provide full path to the shapefiles. Right now arcpy cannot find your files.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what I was doing wrong with the path!!

Comment: Great! Please share your solution so it may help people in the future.

Comment: One thing that helps, especially as a beginning programmer, is to create the variables for the input/output features before executing tools. Also, you can use `if arcpy.Exists(featureclass):` to check for whether a shapefile path is correct before attempting to execute the function.

Comment: Thanks I will use that to check shapefiles. IN the code I posted above the in clip analysis I `clip_features="Buffered_Lake5.shp"` but I saved the file as `"Buffered_Lakes5.shp"`

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the spaces out of your file path: you have "GEOG M173" as one of your folders. Probably too late to help with your class...